# RevoScaleR can not find file, directory that exists

Tags: microsoft-r

I am using RevoscaleR and I have successfully converted csv files to xdf files which I have saved to my local disk.

However, when I try to run functions that call these xdf files I get an error message that there is no such file or directory:

```
The file or directory 'P:/PROPENSITY/CL_Generic_Retail_201506' cannot be found.
```

Let me expose the whole process:

My working directory:

```
> getwd()
[1] "P:/PROPENSITY"
```

I used this code to convert csv file to xdf:

```
rx_CL_Generic_Retail_201506 <- rxImport(
  
  inData = "CL_Generic_Retail_201506_23-05-2017.csv",
  
  outFile = "CL_Generic_Retail_201506.xdf",
  
  overwrite = TRUE
  
)
```

Then I used this code to check that the conversion was successful:

```
rxSummary(formula = ~ Avg_Deposits + Total_Num_ + Sumof_CC_AVGBAL_,  
          
          data = "CL_Generic_Retail_201506.xdf"
          
)


Summary Statistics Results for: ~Avg_Deposits + Total_Num_ + Sumof_CC_AVGBAL_
Data: "CL_Generic_Retail_201506.xdf" (RxXdfData Data Source)
File name: CL_Generic_Retail_201506.xdf
Number of valid observations: 7155413 

Name             Mean        StdDev      Min        Max        ValidObs MissingObs
Avg_Deposits     4562.914627 128614.5683 -325684032 69317080.0 7155413        0   
Total_Num_          7.062068    247.1506          1   224579.0  831567  6323846   
Sumof_CC_AVGBAL_  951.484138   2249.3149          0   164746.6  601304  6554109
```

Up to that point everything was fine.

I continued to convert files to xdf files.

Then I returned to that same file and tried to run the same function (summary) and I got the following error message:

```
> rxSummary(formula = ~ Avg_Deposits + Total_Num_ + Sumof_CC_AVGBAL_,  
+           
+           data = "CL_Generic_Retail_201506.xdf"
+           
+ )

The file or directory 'CL_Generic_Retail_201506.xdf' cannot be found.
```

In case I repeat the process and run again rxImport the rxSummary function runs again.  But then after a while, the same error repeats.

**Could this have to do with back slashes?**

I.e.:  The message is:

```
The file or directory 'P:\PROPENSITY\CL_Generic_Retail_201506.xdf' cannot be found.
```

But when I ask R to print the working directory it returns:

```
> getwd()
[1] "P:/PROPENSITY"
```

Observe that in the RevoScaleR error message the slashes are \ while R's output of getwd() has /.

If this is the problem what I could do about it?

By the way this problem occurs in a workstation where Windows and RevoScaleR are installed.  In a notebook running also RevoScaleR the problem does not appear.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Here is an image of the directory where it is apparent that the files exist.
[Image of the PROPENSITY folder with the xdf files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNvdR.png)

Comment: Backslashes shouldn't be a problem. Have you verified that the file is indeed there? After you get the error, open Explorer and have a look at what's in that Propensity folder.

Comment: Yes the files are there.  I have included an image of that folder.

Comment: That first message up there is missing a `.xdf` file extension.

Comment: Have you tried providing the full path in double quotes, as in:


data = "P:\\PROPENSITY\\CL_Generic_Retail_201506.xdf"


With the slashes escaped, as shown?

Answer (score 0):

Try using append = "rows". The last csv is probably empty, resulting in overwritting a xdf with an empty xdf which is no file.

```
rx_CL_Generic_Retail_201506 <- rxImport(inData = "CL_Generic_Retail_201506_23-05-2017.csv", outFile = "CL_Generic_Retail_201506.xdf",  overwrite = TRUE,
append = "rows"
)
```